# Unable to read files in resources folder - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nsbundle

I am trying to read a file placed in a directory `Object Bank`, inside the resources folder.

```
//Get path for file in object bank
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileId ofType:@"eam" inDirectory:@"Object Bank"];
NSError *error=nil;

//Check if it is present at the location
Boolean prepositioned=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
NSLog(@"File Found : %@",prepositioned?@"Yes":@"No");

//This outputs "File Found : Yes"

//Read file
NSString *fileContents=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"Prepostioned content length: %d",fileContents.length);
//This outputs "Prepostioned content length: 0"

//if file is present:
if (!error) {
    //Do something

}
else
{   
    //Print the error
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.description);
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)" UserInfo=0x8c410d0 {NSFilePath=/Users/ctb/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/16881651-3790-4C87-A3A0-1E1D60563684/OAS IPAD.app/Object Bank/70118600.eam, NSStringEncoding=4}
```

The path does not return `nil` even when the file is not present and the `fileExistsAtPath:path` always returns yes irrespective of whether the file is present or not.

I've tried this as well:

```
NSArray *paths =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"eam" inDirectory:@"Object Bank"];
for (NSString *path in paths) {
    NSString *fileString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Resource : %u ",fileString.length);
}
```

But it has the same problem.

Comment: u want to read it from the ducument's directory?

Answer (score 0):

You're not reading from the `Resources` folder. You're trying to read from the `Object Bank` directory. Getting back `nil` makes sense, since the file doesn't exist there.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileId ofType:@"eam" inDirectory:@"Object Bank"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSLog(@"file exist");
    }
```

Below is the screenshot where I tried to read the text file named `pk` from the resource directory. Hope it helps. Happy coding :-)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question...
I have a folder called "Object Bank" inside the resources folder. The required files may or may not be present there.
But I'm unable to read the file even when it's present there.
And `fileExistsAtPath` returns yes even when the file is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Make absolutely and positively sure that your file to read is of NSUTF8StringEncoding, otherwise you'll have this type of error, which is misleading in not telling you that it wasn't read due to mismatch encoding.

Open your file (fileId of type eam) with say TextWrangler and check what encoding it has, then use that one in the encoding parameter.

Answer (score 0):

i had to add the `file://` prefix to the url

```
guard let resourceString = Bundle.main.resourcePath,
    let fileURL = URL(string: "file://\(resourceString)/mock.txt") else {

    print(">>> url fail")
    return
}

do {

    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

    print(">>> \(string)")

} catch let error {

    print(">>> failed: \(error)")
    return
}
```